# SQLAlchemy Inheritance - Foreign keys do not resolve when using the same base table

Tags: python, inheritance, orm, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I'd like for some of my tables to be able to access models via foreign keys, using SqlAlchemy's [relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship) function. Unfortunately, I'm running into an issue where the foreign keys do not appear to resolve.

What I'm doing differently from the standard SqlAlchemy docs is using an inheritance structure where most tables inherit from the same base.

Tables:

```
Noun:
  nounId INT

Person:
  nounId INT PRIMARY KEY References(Noun.nounId)
  name STRING

Place:
  nounId INT PRIMARY KEY References(Noun.nounId)
  location STRING

Plan:
  nounId INT PRIMARY KEY References(Noun.nounId)
  personId INT References(Person.nounId)
  plan STRING

Trip:
  nounId INT PRIMARY KEY References(Noun.nounId)
  planId INT References(Plan.nounId)
  placeId INT References(Place.nounId)
  plan STRING
```

Currently, I'm unable to get SqlAlchemy to resolve the `plan`.`person` model and I'm unsure as to why. (I'd also like to be able to resolve `person`.`places` via [SqlAlchemy's secondary](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#composite-secondary-joins), but I think the two issues might be related).

The following code will raise an error at the "assert" line:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *

def test():

    metadata = MetaData()

    # Base Table
    nounTable = Table(
        'Nouns', metadata,
        Column('nounId', Integer, primary_key=True)
    )

    personsTable = Table(
        'Persons', metadata,
        Column('nounId', Integer, ForeignKey('Nouns.nounId'), primary_key=True),
        Column('name', String)
    )

    placesTable = Table(
        'Places', metadata,
        Column('nounId', Integer, ForeignKey('Nouns.nounId'), primary_key=True),
        Column('location', String)
    )

    plansTable = Table(
        'Plans', metadata,
        Column('nounId', Integer, ForeignKey('Nouns.nounId'), primary_key=True),
        Column('personId', Integer, ForeignKey('Persons.nounId')),
        Column('plan', String)
    )

    tripsTable = Table(
        'Trips', metadata,
        Column('nounId', Integer, ForeignKey('Nouns.nounId'), primary_key=True),
        Column('planId', Integer, ForeignKey('Plans.nounId')),
        Column('placeId', Integer, ForeignKey('Places.nounId')),
        Column('plan', String)
    )

    class Noun(object): pass
    class Person(Noun): pass
    class Place(Noun): pass
    class Plan(Noun): pass
    class Trip(Noun): pass

    mapper(Noun, nounTable)
    mapper(Trip, tripsTable, inherits=Noun)
    mapper(Place, placesTable, inherits=Noun)

    mapper(Plan, plansTable, inherits=Noun, properties={
        # SqlAlchemy will raise an exception if `foreign_keys` is not explicitly defined
        'person': relationship(Person, foreign_keys=[personsTable.c.nounId], backref='plans')
    })
    mapper(Person, personsTable, inherits=Noun, properties={
        # This is not resolved either
        'places': relationship(Place,
            secondary = join(Plan, Trip, Plan.nounId==Trip.planId),
            secondaryjoin = lambda: Trip.placeId==Place.nounId,
            primaryjoin = lambda: Person.nounId==Plan.personId
        )
    })

    engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
    metadata.create_all(engine)

    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
    alice = Person()
    alice.name = "alice"
    session.add(alice)
    session.commit()

    planA = Plan()
    planA.personId = alice.nounId
    planA.plan = "This is a plan"
    session.add(planA)
    session.commit()
    # The reference isn't resolved
    assert planA.person, "No person found"
    print "Plan: {}".format([planA.nounId, planA.person])

test()
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to retrieve all `Persons` at a `place` and vice versa, but currently, it is not able to resolve the simple `Plan`->`Person` relationship.

Comment: `foreign_keys=[personsTable.c.nounId]` should be `foreign_keys=[plansTable.c.personId]`. It's ["a list of columns which are to be used as “foreign key” columns, or columns which refer to the value in a remote column"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.foreign_keys).

Comment: @IljaEverilä Ah yep, that was it for the first part, thanks! Any ideas on getting person.places?